# how to filter by field contain another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a field of "content" and a field of a "country".
and I need to check if the country name appears in the text's content.

**content:**

- "La baguette est originaire de France"
- "החומוס הטוב ביותר הוא בישראל"
- "Michael Phelps earned his final gold medal when the United States
  team won the 4×100-meter medley relay."

**country:**

- France
- ישראל
- United States

using like clause seems to be the right option, but I don't know how to use the values in the country field for this type of check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive approach with dictionary table:

```
CREATE TABLE country(id INT, name NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO country(id, name) VALUES (1, 'United States'), (2, 'France'), (3, N'ישראל');

SELECT *
FROM mytable m
JOIN country c
  ON m.content LIKE '%' + c.name + '%';
```

Of course it is not bullet-proof solution, because country could be different depending on language and noun case.

**EDIT:**

If country is present on the same row:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN m.content  LIKE '%' + m.country + '%' THEN 'Present' ELSE 'None' END
FROM mytable m
```

Answer (score 0):

As you just need to check the data from other table you can just have a subquery or as per your data row by row to do it without subquery like

```
    SELECT Case
    when Content Like '%'+country+'%' 
     then "Yes" else "No" end, content, 
     country from table ;
```

or via subquery

```
   SELECT 
     content, 
     country from table where content IN 
      (Select '%'+country+'%' from table ) 
       ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
where Content like N'%' + country + N'%'
```

This would return rows where the country is in the content. You seem to have multiple character sets, so I think `nvarchar()` is appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Attached answer using PostgreSQL.
I used the position function but there are similar functions for other databases (instr for Oracle, for example).

```
select * from $table_name$ a
where position(country in content) > 0;
```